# Userscript to capture all URLs on a page and display in a new div layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, userscripts

I am new to JavaScript, so please excuse me if the question is too obvious.

I am writing a greasemonkey script to capture all the hrefs present on a webpage and display them as a new div.
Following is the code that I have been using:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        GetURLs
// @namespace   xyz
// @description Collect all the URLs present on the page
// @include     https://www.google.com/*
// @include     https://www.google.co.in/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var snapshotResults = document.evaluate('//a/@href',document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
//var div = '<div style="width:100%">';
var div = '<div style="background-color:green;width:300px;height:100px;position:relative;top:-220px;left:120px;z-index:83666;">'
window.alert("First message\n"+ snapshotResults.snapshotItem(1).textContent);

for(var i = 0 ; i<snapshotResults.snapshotLength ; i++)
  {
    var href = snapshotResults.snapshotItem(i).textContent ;
    href = href + '<br/>';
    div += href ;
  }

div += '</div>';
alert("After for loop\n"+ div);
$('body').append(div);
```

Following is the output that I am getting:

Results of the first alert box:

> First message
>
> http://www.google.co.in/intl/en/options/

The result of the second alert is the entire result of the snapshotResults within the < div>< /div> tags.

But there is no div layer created and appended at the end of body tag.

Can someone help me with this ?
Also, is the process I am using to create and display a new div layer on a webpage an optimal one, or some other way is commonly used ?

My end goal is to capture all the URLs on a webpage and display them as a separate new overlay layer on the same page, something similar to what is being done in the answer to the question here: [Add dynamic div-layers (overlay) with a Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638947/add-dynamic-div-layers-overlay-with-a-greasemonkey-script)

The script mentioned here works completely fine(with some modifications) for me without the use of unsafeWindow functionality of grease-monkey.
Thus, if using unsafe window is the option for my case, can someone suggest a way without using unsafeWindow.(as I have been reading the grease-monkey documentation and unsafe window has some vulnerabilities.)

Note: Could not post the snapshots of the results obtained as a minimum of 10 reputation was needed to post an image in a question, which presently I don't have.

Comment: There's a typo in your `for` loop: `snapshotResults.snaphotLength`.

Comment: Well thanks. This is embarrassing. I'll edit the question after removing the typo.

Comment: I think your problem now lies with the fact you set the `height` of the `<div>` to `100px`, but set its `top` to `-120px`. It is entirely outside the window.

Comment: @Phylogenesis That was my first thought too. I tried various combinations there. I also used the commented out code (just before the initialization of div variable), but to no avail.

Comment: Then I'm not really sure. I copied/pasted your code into a userscript and it worked for me (after setting `top` and `left` to `0` in the `style` attribute).